# Netty: How to receive variable length message on the server without any header / field indicating length

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to implement a TCP server in java using Netty. I am able to handle message of length < 1024 correctly but when I receive message more than 1024, I am only able to see partial message.

I did some research, found that I should implement replayingdecoder but I am unable to understand how to implement the decode method

My message uses JSON

Netty version 4.1.27

```
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, ByteBuf byteBuf, List<Object> list) throws Exception
```

My Server setup

```
    EventLoopGroup group;

    group = new NioEventLoopGroup(this.numThreads);

    try {
        ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap;
        RequestHandler requestHandler;
        ChannelFuture channelFuture;

        serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        serverBootstrap.group(group);
        serverBootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        serverBootstrap.localAddress(new InetSocketAddress("::", this.port));

        requestHandler = new RequestHandler(this.responseManager, this.logger);

        serverBootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(requestHandler);
            }
        });

        channelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind().sync();
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        this.logger.info(String.format("Unknown failure %s", e.getMessage()));
    }
    finally {
        try {
            group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            this.logger.info(String.format("Error shutting down %s", e.getMessage()));
        }

    }
```

My current request handler

```
package me.chirag7jain.Response;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class RequestHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private ResponseManager responseManager;
private Logger logger;

public RequestHandler(ResponseManager responseManager, Logger logger) {
    this.responseManager = responseManager;
    this.logger = logger;
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf byteBuf;
    String data, hostAddress;

    byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
    data = byteBuf.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
    hostAddress = ((InetSocketAddress) ctx.channel().remoteAddress()).getAddress().getHostAddress();

    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
        String reply;

        this.logger.info(String.format("Data received %s from %s", data, hostAddress));
        reply = this.responseManager.reply(data);

        if (reply != null) {
            ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(reply, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        }
    }
    else {
        logger.info(String.format("NO Data received from %s", hostAddress));
    }
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    this.logger.info(String.format("Received Exception %s", cause.getMessage()));
    ctx.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would accept data in channelRead() and accumulate it in a buffer. Before return from channelRead() I would invoke read() on a Channel. You may need to record other data, as per your needs.
When netty invokes channelReadComplete(), there is a moment to send whole buffer to your ResponseManager.

> **Channel read()**: Request to Read data from the Channel into the first
>   inbound buffer, triggers an
>   *ChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext, Object)* event
>   if data was read, and triggers a *channelReadComplete* event so the
>   handler can decide to continue reading.

Your Channel object is accessible by ctx.channel().

Try this code:

```
private final AttributeKey<StringBuffer> dataKey = AttributeKey.valueOf("dataBuf");

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf byteBuf;
    String data, hostAddress;

    StringBuffer dataBuf = ctx.attr(dataKey).get();
    boolean allocBuf = dataBuf == null;
    if (allocBuf) dataBuf = new StringBuffer();

    byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
    data = byteBuf.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
    hostAddress = ((InetSocketAddress) ctx.channel().remoteAddress()).getAddress().getHostAddress();

    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
        this.logger.info(String.format("Data received %s from %s", data, hostAddress));
    }
    else {
        logger.info(String.format("NO Data received from %s", hostAddress));
    }

    dataBuf.append(data);
    if (allocBuf) ctx.attr(dataKey).set(dataBuf);

    ctx.channel().read();
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    StringBuffer dataBuf = ctx.attr(dataKey).get();
    if (dataBuf != null) {
        String reply;

        reply = this.responseManager.reply(dataBuf.toString());

        if (reply != null) {
            ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(reply, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        }
    }
    ctx.attr(dataKey).set(null);

    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: Didn't really understand it

Comment: See edit. You may need to tweak it a bit, but there you have all you need.

Answer (score 0):

An application protocol with variable length messages must have:

- a length word
- a terminator character or sequence, which in turn implies an escape character in case the data contains the terminator
- a self-describing protocol such as XML.

Comment: I am using JSON

Comment: Does not only have to have these. You can write a VARINT in order to prepend the  payload length. [Var Int Sample](https://github.com/addthis/stream-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/clearspring/analytics/util/Varint.java) . He could do this in the replaying decoder or his own custom handler. I personally implement a packet id protocol that the packet id tells me the payload length field type; I.E byte, short, medium or varint, then read that field, then the data.